# Changing cell data on gridView on DevExp

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, setvalue

I'm writing an audit program and I've got a problem. I use DevExp on the list, if the staff is audited on the control part, I would like to put a red cross if the green tick is not audited. But I could not do it with DevExp. Could you help?

gridView1 view: http://i.hizliresim.com/7Dqd75.jpg

I tried them

```
 for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, colAUDITSTATUS).ToString() == "False")
               {
                   gridView1.SetRowCellValue(i, colCHECK, btnCheck);
               } 
        }
```

I have identified the **okButton** object in the properties of gridView1 in the **In-place Editor Repository**.

The code works fine, but it does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ColumnEdit` proprety of `colAUDITSTATUS` column to an instance of `RepositoryItemCheckEdit` and handle it there (see the comments in my code).

```
var repositoryItemCheckEdit1 = new  DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit();

repositoryItemCheckEdit1.AutoHeight = false;
repositoryItemCheckEdit1.Caption = "Audited";
repositoryItemCheckEdit1.CheckStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckStyles.UserDefined; // <-- important!!!!!
repositoryItemCheckEdit1.Images = imageList; // <--- put an image control on your form and add red and green icons in it
repositoryItemCheckEdit1.ImageIndexChecked = 0; // <-- depends on your indexes in imageControl
repositoryItemCheckEdit1.ImageIndexUnhecked = 1;  // <-- depends on your indexes in imageControl
repositoryItemCheckEdit1.Name = "repositoryItemCheckEdit1";


colAUDITSTATUS.ColumnEdit = this.repositoryItemCheckEdit1;
```